# Jquery toggle activating on multiple elements instead of the element specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

alrighty Ive got what I hope is a rather easy question today for people knowledgeable in jquery. I have an toggle that activates on clicking a specific element, in this case I have targeted my logo image with an id of #logobutton. it works wonderfully however theres a problem, the animation also activates whenever I click on any and all other links on the page and even some random div boxed (like my nav bg). please note im very new to this javaScript jazz so I may be missing something you would consider quite obvious. thanks for the help!

here is the fiddle with all relevant code http://jsfiddle.net/tRf36/1/

jquery:

```
!--jquery script, must be above all jquery elements-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!--script for bg toggle-->
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#logobutton").click(function() {  
        $(".galbox").toggleClass("galbox-change");  
    });  
});


</script>
<!--bg fade hide on load-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gallerybox").fadeTo(3000, 0.00, function() {
         $("#gallerybox").fadeTo(1000, 1.00);
    });
});
</script>
```

hopefully someone can see if I have something targeted incorrectly or whatever is causing the issue of my generic rather than specific selection of clickable area to activate this bg animation.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant markup? Your code looks OK. The fiddle works for me properly using FF.

Comment: you have two `ready` handlers, but that shouldn't be related to the effects you experience. btw, it's java_script_ jazz, not java ... (nit-picking, of course)

Comment: oh wow, i mean its ugly as can be in ff but the other elements dont target it....ive only been looking in chrome so far. what do you mean relevant markup? I posted the code I thought was relevant to my dilema, am I missing some that would make the topic more informative?

Comment: oh I thought i needed a ready handler for each new jquery script, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer was completely off base, sorry for that. Looking at the jsfiddle that you posted it appears that you have the logo button like this `<button ... />` the browser is then ignoring the /> and just wrapping everything in a button. So that means that both the gallery box and the nav bar are surrounded by the button that is activating the animation. Changing the button to be like this should fix it:

`<button type="button" class="logo" id="logobutton" value=""></button>`

Comment: mmmmm I tried removing the link from the html on the nav quickly and it still animates when theyre clicked as simple list items. so far i have found that unless I include $(document).ready() for jquery elements they just dont work. is this not nessisairy? or rather is there a better way to write the code so that it works only onclick instead of when the page loads?

Comment: my goodness thanks! I must have confused my button type for one of those ones that dont need a closing div.

Answer (score 0):

close `<button>` tag properly using `</button>`

All elements below button are treated as children if you do not close properly.

Comment: Correct! however someone beat you to it. thanks a bunch for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Two aspects conspire to cause the effect:

- You have nested your nav bar divs inside the `#logobutton` button.
- Event bubbling causes events triggered on an embedded element to eventually reach the `#logobutton` button, being processed by the registered event handler.

A solution is to check for the triggering element of the click event:

```
$("#logobutton").click(function (eve) {
   if ($(eve.target).attr("id") === "logobutton") {
       $(".galbox").toggleClass("galbox-change");
   }
});
```

You can test this modification  [with this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRf36/5/).

You can learn more about event bubbling in particular and event processing in browsers following these links:

- [quirksmode (ppk)](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)

Comment: a brilliant solution, ill have to remember it for when I need to target a specific id within an element like this, however all i really need to do is close off my button. Thanks so much for the feedback!